# How to determine the name of a previously referenced, now missing, MonoBehaviour script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project with warnings:

```
The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing!
```

I've identified which game objects have these bad references, and I have a collection of scripts (cs files) which I know include the intended scripts, but which component instances (and their saved state) map to which scripts I cannot discern obviously.

Is there a way to know which scripts the components with missing references were originally pointing to, so I can manually reassign the correct scripts back onto the components and preserve component state?

Comment: so any luck with my solution?

Comment: @JeanLuc, Somewhat, thank you. Turns out many of the scripts had no serialized state. I was still left with the "pick the correct 2 out of these 8 stateless scripts." Your answer helped reduce the number of permutations to try before I seemed to have gotten things restored.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337312/how-to-move-a-monobehaviour-to-an-external-assembly-and-dont-get-stuck-in-the.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure in the Editor Settings the Asset Serialization Mode is on “Force Text”.

You could open up your scene (or prefab) file in a text editor and search for the GameObject name with the missing script reference e.g. “TheGameObjectWithTheMissingBehaviour”

you should see something like this (i just copied down the important lines)

```
--- !u!1 &298606752
GameObject:
  m_Component:
  - 54: {fileID: 1199074165}
  - 114: {fileID: 1199074166}
  m_Name: TheGameObjectWithTheMissingBehaviour
---
```

below the GameObject there should be a list with at least one MonoBehaviour, which looks like this

```
--- !u!114 &1199074166
MonoBehaviour:
  m_Enabled: 1
  _myCustomVariableA: 1
  _myCustomVariableB: 2
  _myCustomVariableC: 2
---
```

you can see in the last lines there are the custom variable i.e. [SerializedField] or public members.

then you could search your project for a script with those custom variable name.

Comment: I just want to add some information: you can notice that the MonoBehaviour ids are also listed under `m_Component` of the GameObject you searched for. But you still need to check below anyway because other components (like Transforms) are in this list as well.